# Why is my JList/JScrollPane so small?

Tags: java, layout, jscrollpane, jlist

When I run my code the JList shows up but it's really small, and when I try to change its size it won't change size. What am I doing that's wrong? A lot of the GUI formatting is new to me. Thanks.

```
public class Panel extends JPanel
{
//Fields
private Dimension dimensions; 
private JButton button1; 
private JList list; 
private JScrollPane listScroller; 
private String title;
private DefaultListModel model; 

/**
 * Constructor 
 */

public Panel()
{
    dimensions = new Dimension(400, 300);
    setPreferredSize(dimensions);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLayout(null); //Lets me lay my components out freely 

    button1 = new JButton("New Set"); 
    button1.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(150, 250), button1.getPreferredSize()));
    button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    add(button1);

    String[] titleArray ={title};
    model = new DefaultListModel(); 
    for(String title :titleArray)
    {
        model.addElement(title); 
    }
    list = new JList(model);
    list.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(200,200), list.getPreferredSize()));
    add(list);

    listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
    listScroller.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(200,200), listScroller.getPreferredSize()));
    add(listScroller);
}
}
```

Comment: "`setLayout(null);`" <- There's your problem.

Comment: Also, your model is empty, so the preferred size is probably (0, 0). You can easily verify this with a simple display statement. Use the `setVisibleRowCount(...)` method to allow the JList to determine the appropriate size size for the list.

Comment: @resueman can you explain a bit further?

Comment: @SeanGui. Using a `null` layout is never a good idea. It may seem easier, but it results in a lot of unexpected problems. The right approach is to use nested [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to create the design you want.

Comment: @resueman I understand, I'll try to go back to nested layouts then. Thanks